# CSS: How To Put Boxes Inside A Column

Tags: css, css-float, css-tables

I'm trying to replace a two column table on my index page with CSS.  To get a look at my current index page, it is at http://www.negative-g.com.

I have my columns set up. I'm actually using a three column layout with the third being for my sidebar image, and for the other two I want to have boxes (basically tables without using tables) with images and text alternating (park logos and their name/location in text underneath lined up with those in the other column).  What sort of code would I need to add to each column to replicate my table layout?

Comment: [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Usually I'd use a bunch of floated blocks for that. For example, if I've got a list of items:

```
<ul>
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Bar</li>
    <li>Baz</li>
    <li>Quux</li>
</ul>
```

(After removing all the margins and padding) I can set dimensions on the `li` elements, make them blocks, and float them left:

```
li {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
```

If there's only 200px of space for them, then they'll wrap around. **[Try it.](http://jsfiddle.net/ym95x/)**

If you set the width to 50%, [you'll get a two-column layout](http://jsfiddle.net/tYfFG/). Remove the height, style the interior, and you're good to go.

This doesn't take your sidebar into account, but your sidebar isn't really part of the list, and you appear to be dealing with it as a background anyway, so there shouldn't really be any need for anything special. If you want to make sure the list doesn't overlap it, you can set a `margin-right` on the list and it won't go over there.

Comment: Ok this is probably a simple question but I don't totally get CSS and everything I have done has been with an insane amount of trial and error.  So what you're saying is to ditch the two column layout (ignore that the background is the third one) - the two columns of names/logos and just float them as blocks.  Then if the browser window was wide there would be more than two in a row and if it were smaller it would scale down like word wrapping?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: D'oh looked at what you wrote again and it is a one column, set the right margin for the column to always have enough room for my image and then set the image as a background image positioned right?

Comment: @PaulDrabek: You can treat the list of roller coasters as one column when the layout of the rest of the page is concerned. My answer addresses how to make the items within the list be laid out in two columns.

Comment: Ok...got the LI to work but now when I view the page in a browser the image in the right column keeps getting pushed below where all the LI's are.  Any idea how to keep that from happening?

Comment: Also is there any way to make it so there is a minimum width for the LI's?  When I scale the window down some of my images are getting covered up by the sidebar image.  I tried to add}
li {
 display: block;
 width: 50%;
 min-width: 300px;
 height: 110px;
 float: left;
 color: white;
But then it caused everything to stack.

Comment: @PaulDrabek: If you set the right-column image as a background on the `body` as you appear to be doing, that shouldn't happen. As for a minimum width, you're doing it right: if there's not enough space for two columns, it will indeed transition into a one-column layout. If instead you want it to just hide the background image, you could set a minimum width on the `ul` and make the background of the `ul` black.